# I want to copy existing table from one schema to another without changing anything

Tags: sql, oracle, dbvisualizer

I am trying to copy 1 table from 1 schema into another schema in non existing table using DBVizualizer or SQL Developer.
Also if possible just for testing purposes will need example how to copy 1 table into another (non existing table) in the same schema.

I would really appreciate any help.

Have tried this:

```sql
SELECT * 
INTO new_table 
FROM old_table;
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE old_table 
RENAME TO new_table;
```

in both DBVizuallizer and SQL Developer doesn't work and I am not really sure what I have done since it was copy paste from w3school.

Comment: The SELECT ... INTO syntax is not valid SQL in oracle.  It _is_ valid PL/SQL, but in that usage, the target of the INTO is a PL/SQL variable, not a table/column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTAS (Create Table As Select) is a simple option:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table dept_new as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> select * from dept_new;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

However, if a new table should reside in another schema, then you might have a problem because you can't create objects in other schemas **unless** you have privileges to do so. Normally, we don't because that requires `create any table` privilege, and that's not something you (or your DBA) should grant easily.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table mike.dept_new as select * From dept;
create table mike.dept_new as select * From dept
                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create any table to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table mike.dept_new as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Presuming that another schema already contains such a table (but it is empty), you'd just copy data. But, that also won't be easy because of - guess what? - missing privileges. We aren't supposed to mess up with other users' data.

```
SQL> insert into mike.dept_new select * From dept;
insert into mike.dept_new select * From dept
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

This time we don't need a DBA to grant privileges; other user (`mike`) can do that:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> grant insert on dept_new to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> insert into mike.dept_new select * From dept;

4 rows created.

SQL>
```

---

Yet another option is to export data from source schema and import it into target schema. First, drop it from `mike` (as you said that it shouldn't already exist):

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> drop table dept_new;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Export:

```
SQL> $exp scott/tiger file=dept.dmp tables=dept

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Pro 20 21:41:36 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
Export done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
. . exporting table                           DEPT          4 rows exported
EXP-00091: Exporting questionable statistics.
Export terminated successfully with warnings.
```

Import:

```
SQL> $imp mike/lion file=dept.dmp

Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Pro 20 21:41:50 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by SCOTT, not by you

import done in EE8MSWIN1250 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing SCOTT's objects into MIKE
Import terminated successfully without warnings.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you , CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM OLD_TABLE; Works how i wanted , i really wanted to avoid exporting and importing data since its more work to be done. And i have to write it as a script that will help in future if someone want to prepare the data for testing. So the code can be re-used without to mich extra steps.